# How to trigger TeamCity job upon pull request to release branch

Tags: teamcity, pull-request

I configured Teamcity job to be triggered by pull requests (pull request is created or updated). 
In VCS root default branch:

```
refs/heads/master
```

Branch specification:

```
-:refs/heads/master
+:refs/pull/(*/merge)
```

All our release branches have name started with release-, for example release-1.0.0.

How to configure teamcity job to be triggered only by pull requests to any release branch?
There is pull request filtering by target branch, however it does not support asterisks in name of branch.

Comment: Are you talking about triggers?

Comment: Yes, talking about job triggers

Comment: I might be mistaken here or we're referring to different things but you can create a `VCS Trigger` and then use the following branch filter: `+:release-*`

Comment: I want to analyse pull request, not result of merge to release branch. Git for pull requests creates /pull/ID branch

Answer (score 1):

Here's what finally worked for me, specifically for Bitbucket Cloud. The article that @anton referenced in another answer led to this solution.

In short, my need was:

- Trigger a build when the default branch has new changes
- Trigger a build when a PR is created targeting the default branch

Breaking down the various settings for a given project, these were the ones significant to this issue:

- Version Control Settings

  - VCS Roots

    - VCS Root

      - Default branch

        - Use the value for your default branch, such as `refs/heads/main`
      - Branch specification

        - Leave blank (my need was to only build the default branch and PR's)
    - Additional Options

      - Branch Filter

        - Use `+:*`
- Triggers

  - VCS Trigger

    - Branch Filter

      - Use `+:*`
- Build Features

  - Pull Requests

    - Pull Request Filtering

      - By target branch

        - Use `+:refs/heads/main` to trigger all PR's that have this branch as the target branch

So, what we have now is that TeamCity can see the VCS Root branch that was specified as default branch, AND it can see additional branches that are added to the list by the Pull Requests feature.

Finally, nothing will trigger until a trigger is added. The trigger looks at all branches *that were made visible to it* as described inthe previous paragraph.

There's certainly room for different approaches here based on the different ways you may want to trigger builds.

*Note to anyone at TeamCity who reads this: Please update the site documentation AND ESPECIALLY the inline help to clarify how this all works. It makes sense, but it took me several hours of digging and trial and error until I happened across this SO question and worked it out. Thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

Due to answer posted by Anton Arhipov [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/08/building-github-pull-requests-with-teamcity/) it's not possible now:

> Hi! Currently, the target branch must be a full name. No regex definitions supported yet